# is this menu button created by CSS or another thing

Tags: css, svg-animate

I m making my new website and I saw this amazing menu button in that

#: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyJSw.png

for more reference, u can directly visit the site on

https://superlist.com/
I can't read its code

i used developer tool but it not showing in animation

Does anyone recommend me where i can learn this type of
CSS animation if it is CSS.

Comment: it uses canvas animation created by GSAP library

Answer (score 0):

The Button is made with Three.js library. its impossible to make it with css